# Jslint can't pass through object

Tags: jslint

I just started to use jslint with backbone. At the beginning of project I create object:

```
 App = {
  Models: {},
  Views: {},
  Controller: {}
 }
```

and get error:" 'App' was used before it was defined."
Then later I use it as:

```
 App.Models.Task = Backbone.Model.extend({})
```

and at this point jslint can't pass me through. it says

unexpected 'App'. App.Models.Task = Backbone.Model.extend({}) // Line 17, Pos 1
 #8 Stopping. (7% scanned).

I've read that probably jslint sees it as critical error because it stopped but it is not an error. what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

It should be `var App` (or `window.App`, depending on your goals; but, in my opinion, even global variables are better defined as local ones first, then exported into outer space within a single statement). Otherwise JSLint (quite rightly) thinks that you just forgot to define this variable in some other place OR made a typo in its name.

Comment: it helps only to solve first error after adding var or window i still get error: unexpected 'App'. App.Models.Task = Backbone.Model.extend({})

Comment: Can you show the whole code then (at least, lines preceding the one with 'App.Models.Task'? These two lines by themselves are Ok with JSLint.

Comment: Ok the problem was line before - i forgot to add ; after }. Thanks a lot.